# keep a nodejs request in waiting until first is completed

Tags: node.js

I have a situation with nodejs api. what I want to archive is when same user is hitting the same API at same time , i want to block or queue his second request until first is completed.
PS- i want to apply this  for same user
thanks in advance

Comment: You can achieve this by manage script on client side. You want handle this for ajax request?

Comment: i want to do this on node side.. i am using http on angular 2

Comment: I don't know why exactly you want to do this from server end. As i know it should be from client side.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using **semaphore**. The semaphore will be based on the client where each client will have only 1 semaphore while receiving a request the server stops receiving another request by locking mechanism and after responding, the lock should be released.

**Demo**:

```
let clientSemaphores = {};
const semaphore = require('semaphore');
var server = require('http').createServer(function(req, res) {
  var client = req.url.split("/")[1];  //client id to specify
  console.log(client, " request recieved");
  if (!clientSemaphores[client] || clientSemaphores[client].current < clientSemaphores[client].capacity){
    clientSemaphores[client] = clientSemaphores[client] || semaphore(1);
    clientSemaphores[client].take(function() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        res.write(client + " Then good day, madam!\n");
        res.end(client + " We hope to see you soon for tea.");
        clientSemaphores[client].leave();
      }, 5000);
    });
  } else {
    res.end(client + " Request already processing... please wait...");
  }
});

server.listen(8000);
```

**OR**

**HTTP Pipelining**

Persistent HTTP allows us to reuse an existing connection between multiple application requests, but it implies a strict first in, first out (FIFO) queuing order on the client: dispatch request, wait for the full response, dispatch next request from the client queue. HTTP pipelining is a small but important optimization to this workflow, which allows us to relocate the FIFO queue from the client (request queuing) to the server (response queuing).
Reference: [HTTP Pipelining](https://hpbn.co/http1x/#http-pipelining)

Comment: @techguy, I have added demo code in the answer section.

Comment: i want to  do this only for 2 apis .. not on server listening

Comment: you can do this by using a global variable `clientSemaphores` and implement the above logic `take` and `leave` on those two endpoints. i have shared the above example to understand it.

Comment: one question , it will queue a request or send user the response

Comment: you can either implement queue system or you can /not can respond to the request. it depends on your requirement, I've made it by making responding to the request.

Comment: if i keep nothing in else part then it will in queue and will be executed when the first request is completed, right?

Comment: No, it won't, you have to implement the `queue` system to process rest request if you want it.

Comment: can you give me some example of that , that would be great

Comment: I would recommend `HTTP Pipelining` to do so, @techguy

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure doing anything on the server side (like semaphores) will solve this issue if the app is both stateless and is going be scaled horizontally in Production over two or more replicas.

- All the Pods (app servers) will have to maintain the same semaphore value for the end-point being used
- I think you can achieve the same mechanism with a Database Flag or use Redis to indicate the operation is in progress on one of the app servers.
- It is as good as having sessions (in terms of maintaining a certain state) as per the client request
- You will also need a recovery mechanism to reset the semaphore if the operation carried out by that end-point fails or crashes the thread.